# How do I punch a hole (FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE) in a file from command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, sparse-files

There is [fallocate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) system call to make sparse files by erasing a "holes" in them. Is there a command line tool for it?

Expecting something like:

```
 makehole myfile.dat --offset=10G --length=1G
```

Answer (score 7):

Looks like my manpage of [fallocate(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html) command line tool is out of date. There is the appropriate option `--punch-hole` (`-p`):

```
fallocate -p -o 10G -l 1G qqq
```

Comment: Note that `--punch-hole` makes a hole no matter what the current contents are and parts of a block too small to punch will be overwritten with zeros on disk. If instead you only want to free blocks of zeros large enough to be replaced by holes use option `--dig-holes`.

Answer (score -2):

man fallocate

```
   -p, --punch-hole
          Punch holes in the file, the range should not exceed the length of the file.
```

Comment: This doesn’t add anything substantive to the existing answer...

Comment: It does has a info.The range should not exceed the length of the file.

Comment: OK, but that’s not actually true, you can specify a range which exceeds the file’s size. The file’s size won’t change, but any content within the specified range will be cleared. Try it and see... The correct manpage is already linked in the previous answer.